# How can I align a logo AND a heading to the centre of a page?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to align a logo to the left of a heading and the two together to the centre of a page, as in the image.

[image: this is actually a screenshot of a pdf which I'm trying to re-style in HTML]

This is as far as I've got after searching SO and playing around with the Chrome developer tools: https://jsfiddle.net/mnevqk1o/1/
HTML:

```
<div class="row text-center" style="width:100%">
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4 osheading pc">
        <div class="oslogo">
            <img src="http://www.zerowasteusa.com/prodImages/BlackIcon_2.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="ostext">
            <h1>Windows User</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
</div>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
.oslogo {
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    vertical-align: middle !important;
}
.osheading {
    vertical-align: middle !important;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    text-align: center;

}
.ostext {
    text-align: left;
}
```

How can I make this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify this greatly. You don't necessarily need to use the grid but can (`use col-*-12 or col-*-4 col-*-offset-4`). And you only need one div and two rules to actually align the text and img.

The examples are vertically centered but those rules are commented in case you're doing something else.

```
.logo-block {
    text-align: center;
}
.logo-block h1 {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

See working Snippet.

```css
.logo-block {
  text-align: center;
}
.logo-block h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  /*Only for Vertical Align Middle*/
  margin: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
/*Only for Vertical Align Middle*/

.logo-block img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<hr>
<div class="container">
  <div class="logo-block">
    <img src="http://www.zerowasteusa.com/prodImages/BlackIcon_2.jpg">
    <h1>Windows User</h1>

  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="logo-block">
        <img src="http://www.zerowasteusa.com/prodImages/BlackIcon_2.jpg">
        <h1>Windows User</h1>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
```

Answer (score 3):

I would remove the two containers and combine them into one.  Then basically use `text-align:center` for the container and make sure both elements are `display:inline-block`.

Here's a fiddle and code:
http://jsfiddle.net/5cb2k3ax/

html

```
<div class="row text-center" style="width:100%">
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4 osheading pc">
        <div class="oslogo">
            <img src="http://www.zerowasteusa.com/prodImages/BlackIcon_2.jpg">
            <h1>Windows User</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
</div>
```

css

```
.oslogo {
    text-align:center;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
.oslogo img,
.oslogo h1{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you, all you're missing is a set width on the

```
.osheading { width:313px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I honestly think this can be solved with code this simple:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row text-center">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <h1>
                <img src="http://www.zerowasteusa.com/prodImages/BlackIcon_2.jpg"/>
                Windows User
            </h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Simply keep the logo and text inline inside the `<h1>` tag, and set it's parent width to 100% (using bootstrap's `<div class="container-fluid">`, `<div class="row">` and `<div class="col-*0-12">` structure.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pkh4qr3y/)

Answer (score -3):

maybe put it in a div tag and align centre
**just maybe**